# Achieve parallax effect using css background-attachment property

Tags: html, css, parallax

Please check this JSBIN link.

http://jsbin.com/axeway/14/edit

When you scroll the page you can see the parallax-like effect on the first div but for some reason, its not working with the other divs. The only difference is the background images.

Not sure what's going on. The remaining divs are just scrolling normally even though i gave them a `background-attachment` property of `'fixed'`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never-mind guys. Its the stupid backgrounds. The `background-attachment` is working but the effect is not noticeable because of the linear gradient.

For anyone coming across a similar issue, the background images should be distinguishable and not just plain colours or gradients.

Comment: I was just going to comment on this. :) Anyway, mark the question answered (by yourself).

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I wasted a lot of time on this today.

Comment: Personally, I do this alot. Trying to get my head around a problem and when I finally write it down and define it, the solution (or error) just jumps right out and bites me in the arse. :)